# how can i solve it " A non null string must be provided to a text widget "

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, uber-api

When I try to write a location name it shows this error. Here is the code of the widget I used to predict the location name:

```dart
class PredictionTile extends StatelessWidget
{
  final PlacePredictions placePredictions;

  PredictionTile({Key key, this.placePredictions}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
          Row(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.add_location,color: Colors.redAccent,),
              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                    Text(placePredictions.main_text,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),), //show suggestion
                    SizedBox(height: 3.0,),
                    Text(placePredictions.secondary_text,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,color: Colors.grey),),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to prevent the error from happening.

1. You could mark the two properties of `PlacePredictions` class as `required` in the `PlacePredictions` constructor.

   ```
   PlacePredictions({required this.main_text, required this.secondary_text});
   ```

This way, your IDE will warn you whenever you forget to pass in those two properties.

2. Else, you could set a default value for them if you can't or don't want to pass in a value whenever you create a `PlacePredictions` instance.
3. Finally, you can always [handle this logic](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#conditional-expressions) in the widget itself.

   ```
   Text(placePredictions.main_text ?? 'oops no text here');
   ```

Comment: @required for dart < 2.12